# Total Chloride Vs Organic/Inorganic Chloride

Tags: analytical-chemistry, halogens

I am currently running a project to detect chloride level in crude palm oil. On most lab service websites, some offer total chloride detection and others offer organic chloride detection. What are the differences between total chloride and organic chloride?

Comment: How long have you been thinking and searching to get an answer to this  question, before asking ? What is the difference between ( fruits and vegetables ) and ( just fruits ) ?  Is chlorine in DDT organic or inorganic ?  Is chlorine in table salt organic or inorganic ? Note that there is not expected inorganic chlorine in vegetable oils as lipophilic liquid, unless contained in hydrophilic part of eventual emulsion.

Comment: BTW, you may confuse chlorine and chloride, unless it is meant the total/organic/inorganic chlorine content is expressed as chloride.